# Get global data everywhere in app angular

Tags: javascript, angular, global-variables, behaviorsubject, subject

I have global variables that I need to access everywhere in my app. My project use subject as service state management. I don't want to use NGRX or redux pattern based state management.

I want to get data from Api and set variable in a service when the app loads, whatever the page.
Then data will be get in components from the service.

Should I use a resolver on top parent route as in the code below? I want this api call to be executed only once.

```
const subRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'products', component: productsComponent },
];

export const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: subRoutes,
    resolve: { globalVariables: globalVariablesResolver },
  },
];
```

GlobalVariable resolver will save data in behaviorSubjects in a service. Is it the poper way to do it as I will get data from service and not from `activatedRoute.data` ?

Comment: Did you try just rxjs and its Observables? Just have a service get a value from API, set a new value to BehaviorSubject variable and then subscribe to it in other components.

Comment: @MishaMashina thx for the reply. I indeed want to use a service with behaviorSubject. But where do I make the initial call that set my variables? I want to make this call only once and whatever the entry page

Comment: @MishaMashina I added some code example in my post

Comment: All that code is irrelevant for using observables/subject. You can create a setter and getter methods in a service. Setter will accept a parameter that it will assign to BehaviorSubject variable. Getter will return the current value of BehaviorSubject variable. Some component will subscribe to service's getter method and use the returned value. In some component - app.component.ts for example - you will subscribe to your API endpoint and retrieve the value, then pass it as argument in a call to service's setter method.

Comment: You might need this https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER